# Missing configuration procedures in oracle 11g EE

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

After logging with `sqlplus / as sysdba` then preparing strmadmin user and executing:

`exec dbms_stream_auth.grant_admin_privilege('strmadmin', true);`

I'm getting `PLS-00201: identifier 'DBMS_STREAM_AUTH.GRANT_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE' must be declared`

Why? Am I missing some built in procedures? It's Oracle 11g EE. I'm trying to follow [this](http://oracleocpworld.com/oracle-11g-streams-two-database-replication-environment-with-synchronous-captures/) tutorial.

Comment: It should be `DBMS_STREAMS_AUTH` , you missed the letter `S`.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured it out too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the word `s` (as @Jsapkota mentioned) it should be like this `DBMS_STREAMS_AUTH` , read more about in the [document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_streams_aut.htm#i1000214)

```
DBMS_STREAMS_AUTH.GRANT_ADMIN_PRIVILEGE(
   grantee           IN  VARCHAR2,
   grant_privileges  IN  BOOLEAN   DEFAULT TRUE,
   file_name         IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL,
   directory_name    IN  VARCHAR2  DEFAULT NULL);
```